# What is the easiest way to benchmark a webserver?

Tags: benchmark

I want to compare my home server (Debian 6) and Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu 10.04)

Is there a program that I can simply and download and run to get the comparison values?

I want to compare harddrive I/O, CPU, memory and etc.

Answer (score 2):

To measure actual throughput [Apachebench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is simple but can give you a good first approximation.

After that perhaps you should look into a tool like [Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), which allows you to save test cases relevant to your websites and do stress testing using them.

On Debian the respective packages are `apache2-utils` and `jmeter`.

If you want to stress test the server itself you can run `bonnie++` locally for I/O testing.

To get a comparable approximation on the CPU speed I always run `openssl speed`. It has the advantage of already being there on the majority of servers.